# window.onload not working on mobile phone browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I don't know if anyone can help me out here. I don't know why window.onload with react.js is not working on mobile phone browsers but is working perfectly on my PC browsers. I have been looking for a solution for hours now and I am not even getting anything on google. or maybe anyone can help me with an alternative way to call a function only when the window loads. I don't want the function to get called when I click to another page and come back to the page (for example if the function I want to call once is on home page, when I click from home page to another page and I come back to home page I don't want the function to get called. it should get called ONLY when the window loads or reloads) so useEffect with an empty dependency array can't work. Any help will be greatly appreciated, I am losing brain cells on this problem

```
window.onload = GetData;
```

```
  window.onload = async function callData() {
    console.log("called data");
    await GetData();
  };
```

```
window.onload = () =>  setTimeout(GetData, 1500)
```

I have tried these and some others too and they all worked on my PC browsers but not mobile phone browsers

Comment: Why would you use `window.onload` in react? ` Just add the code to `useEffect` in the app component - it will run once

Comment: Yes, it will run once, but if I leave the page and come back to it the function gets called again, but with windows.onload it only gets called when you load or refresh the page

Comment: How would you leave the app component other than doing a reload?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-morning-3n9cp6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I can click on a link to another page. When I put the function in useEffect and use an empty dependency array it will run once as expected, but when I click to another page on the site and come back to the home page react calls the useEffect again which calls the function again. With windows.onload you have to manually refresh (top left corner of pressing f5) for the function to get called again, which is what I want. Meaning even if I leave the page and come back it doesn't get called, it should only get called when the user refreshes the page or enters for the first time

Comment: You are adding your `useEffect` in the wrong component